# new R studio (Version 0.98.507) ggsave

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I just installed the newest version of R Studio (Version 0.98.507) and it's having problems when I save my ggplots with ggsave (that weren't there in the oldest version). In particular, instead of saving the plots with the normal size, it's doing a screen capture of the plot that appears in the console, with the size that the console have in the moment when I run the script.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: iirc that was always what `ggsave` did. Study `help("ggsave")` and use the `width` and `height` parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I know, but still all the quality of the image is worst when I run the same script (including the typography, for example).

Comment: try adding a `type = "cairo-png"` (or `cairo-…` for whatever output format you're using)